# How to change or to remove an entity/table created by Doctrine2 in Symfony2?

Tags: shell, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

Let's say I've created a wrong entity in the command line, or at least, an entity with the wrong format : yml instead of annotation. And I would like to change that. How could I do ?

I've done

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:entity
configuration format : yml
```

and that's where I wanted annotation.

How could I change that ? If I can't, how could I delete my Entity
Because when I try to generate a CRUD, i have

```
Class XXXXXXXXXX is not a valid entity or mapped super class
```

EDIT: I did it removing the files itself, but I would rather use the shell if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately shell tool do not allow removing bundles etc.